# Redshift Quarter end date and Year end date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, amazon-redshift, plsqldeveloper

How to find quarter end date and year end date in redshift.

I found start date of quater by below query. I need quarter end date and year end date.

DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) as quarter_start_date,

Thanks,

cast(DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) as date) as quarter_start_date,

Comment: In Postgresql, this will do: https://dbfiddle.uk/0MVROhWm, I don't know if in Redshift too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find a **quarter end date** is to **find the start of the quarter, add one quarter (3 months) and then subtract one day**.

Try:

```
DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) + interval '3 months' - interval '1 day'
```

Same for the Year End -- find the start of the year, add 1 year, then subtract 1 day:

```
DATE_TRUNC('year', date) + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day'
```

Comment: Yes Its working with currten_date date but if i pass my date column, I am geting error.   i checked data type is date only.   


   
  ERROR: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported code: 8001 context: interval months: "12" query: 11812773 location: cg_constmanager.cpp:107 process: padbmaster [pid=1073898195] ----------------------------------------------- [ErrorId: 1-64ca019d-7613f29e4a2c83367dba5903]

Comment: We have a limitation to use INTERVAL to use on redshift DB columns.

So we can use below code to get it.
select cast(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, 1, DATE_TRUNC('year',date)))as date) as year_start_date

select cast(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(QTR, 1, DATE_TRUNC('QTR',date)))as date) as quarter_end_date